# Bash: Wait for the current command to complete, but not start any more commands

Tags: bash

I've copied a list of several long-running commands into bash shell and pressed Enter. The commands are now being executed sequentially.

For example:

```
train_agi.sh
find_meaning_of_life.sh
destroy_universe.sh
```

Now I want the current command to complete, but the subsequent commands to be aborted.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I was thinking about terminating the shell, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It would really help us if you add to your question the command expression you've used, so we may help you better. Overall, closing the terminal / terminating the current running tty shouldn't do harm if you know what you are running and what might be the outcome would be.

Comment: Also, please add your Ubuntu flavor and version to your question.

Comment: There is no command expression. As I wrote, I just written 10 lines / 10 commands in a text editor, copied them, opened the terminal with bash, pasted the lines using Ctrl+Shift+V and pressed Enter. Normal interactive terminal....

Comment: My mistake. I've probably chosen wrong StackOverflow website. My question is about Bash, not Ubuntu.

Comment: @Ark-kun, this information is not enough, no matter which Stackoverflow site. Without knowing the commands, it is difficult to help you. You could try add `wait` in between the commands.

Comment: @pLumo Can you please help me understand why you think that the answer depends on specific commands? Does Bash really inspect the binaries it starts and change the behavior? Can you please explain how I can add `wait` between the commands I've *already started*? As I said, I'm working in an interactive terminal and I've *already started the commands*. The currently running command takes 5 hours to finish. Do I need to babysit the terminal for 5 hours slamming Ctrl+C the second it finishes at ~4AM? Is there any better way?

Comment: Sorry, `wait` does not help. It depends on the content of the .sh files. If they contain `sleep 10 &`, the `sleep` will run in the background and the script finishes immediately. If we don't know the content of your scripts, there is nothing we can do

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You can press Ctrl+C, but that will halt the current command and proceed to the next. Pressing Ctrl+C repeatedly will eventually quit out. I am not aware of a method to signal bash to finish the currently running command and discard the following commands.

Comment: @Ark-kun there might be *some* hope based on which commands they are exactly. Bash caches the location of commands in `PATH` if they have been looked up before. If that's not the case, you can escape by moving the files elsewhere, or creating do-nothing override scripts with the same name in a preceding directory in `PATH`, so that bash will either fail to run them or run the overriding scripts instead.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I ultimately went with Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+C, ..., `fg`. It did not fully work as it should have, but it did the job for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to *suspend* all the commands, using Ctrl+Z as many times as there are queued commands, then `kill` the ones that you do not wish to run. You can then resume the first command by placing its job back in the foreground using `fg` (or background using `bg`, if you prefer).

To illustrate:

```
$ /bin/sleep 300 ; /bin/sleep 200 ; /bin/sleep 100
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 /bin/sleep 300
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 /bin/sleep 200
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 /bin/sleep 100
steeldriver@DESKTOP-SPDO14V:~$
steeldriver@DESKTOP-SPDO14V:~$ jobs
[1]   Stopped                 /bin/sleep 300
[2]-  Stopped                 /bin/sleep 200
[3]+  Stopped                 /bin/sleep 100
steeldriver@DESKTOP-SPDO14V:~$
steeldriver@DESKTOP-SPDO14V:~$ kill %2 %3
[2]-  Terminated              /bin/sleep 200
[3]+  Terminated              /bin/sleep 100
steeldriver@DESKTOP-SPDO14V:~$
steeldriver@DESKTOP-SPDO14V:~$ fg %1
/bin/sleep 300
-
```

Comment: Seems racy to me - I tried with Ctrl-Z held down and got this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pGnvvkj9zV/

Comment: Thank you. I've eventually went with Ctrl+Z, but the result was somewhat strange. I've pressed Ctrl+Z and got `^Z
[1]+  Stopped`. I've then pressed Ctrl+C repeatedly until I got the interactive prompt. I then tried to use `fg`, but that resulted in `Segmentation fault`. Calling `fg` again printed `bash: fg: current: no such job`. The program (or main part of it) was still running though. I wanted to follow the job with something else. Calling `wait XXX` resulted in `wait: pid XXX is not a child of this shell`. So I've used loop polling `/proc/XXX` to wait for the job to finish.